# Renomear arquivos com nomes aleatórios usando php

Tags: php

Preciso renomear, de forma aleatória, todos arquivos com a extensão .gif em um diretório. Consegui, usando o seguinte código:

```
$nome = substr(hash('md5',time()),0,10);
foreach (glob("*.gif") as $arquivo) {
    rename($arquivo, $nome . basename($arquivo));
}
```

Porém o arquivo que tinha o nome "exemplo1.gif" passa a se chamar "d8030d37e9exemplo1.gif", o próximo arquivo "d8030d37e9exemplo2.gif"...

Então os ajustes que não estou conseguindo fazer são:

1. O novo nome do arquivo não deve conter o nome original
2. O começo do novo nome está repetido para todos arquivos renomeados ("d8030d37e9")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente isso:

```
foreach (glob("*.gif") as $arquivo) {
    $nome = substr(hash('md5',time().rand()),0,10);
    rename($arquivo, $nome.'.gif');
}
```

- passamos a geração do nome para o loop, para que seja renovado;
- acrescentamos um `rand()` para não depender só do `time()` (que pode repetir facilmente em loop);
- tiramos o nome original do `rename`.

Comment: Funcionou exatamente como queria, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Na versão do PHP 7 existe o [`random_byte`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.random-bytes.php) que teoricamente é mais seguro do que depender do tempo.

```
foreach (glob("*.gif") as $arquivo) {

     $nome = bin2hex( random_bytes(12) );    
     rename($arquivo, $nome . '.gif');

}
```

Isso irá utilizar a função [`random_byte`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.random-bytes.php) irá retornar gerar 12 bytes de maneira *[pseudo-aleatória criptograficamente segura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)*.  O [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.bin2hex.php) é utilizado para retornar em formado hexadecimal, *que é o comum*.

No final terá um nome aleatório de 24 dígitos de extensão a cada arquivo do [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Obrigado, também funcionou como desejado.